# choices js can't swap the value of select between 2 inputs with es5 syntax

Tags: javascript

i want to swap between 2 input selects, but value not update after click the swap button.

this my code :

pug

```
select.form-control.form-control-lg#originInput
    option(placeholder) From
    option Jakarta - CGK

  select.form-control.form-control-lg#destinatnionInput
    option(placeholder) To
    option Yogyakarta - JOG
```

js

```js
var originInput = document.getElementById("originInput")
  var destinationInput = document.getElementById("destinationInput")

  // swap button
  var swap = document.getElementById("swapButton")
  swap.addEventListener("click", function() {
    destinationInput.value = [originInput.value, originInput.value = 
  destinationInput.value][0]
  })
```

but value not exchange, only get empty values.
so, i try to change to es6 syntax and it's works.

```js
swap.addEventListener("click", function() {
  [destinationInput, originInput] = [originInput, destinationInput]
})
```

I don't know why it doesn't work on ES5 ..
and how to update view of value selected??

Comment: Your first `.js` uses `.value`s, your second ES6 syntax doesn't use `.value`s. Just remove the `.value`s in your first `.js`?